# Unable to get Controller model attribute if javascript is enabled in html

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, statusbar

I am developing a Springboot web application where i have a input field which accepts only .csv file. If we will pass any other file it should throw an error on the same page. If CSV file is passed then I have to show the live upload status of file on the HTML file.

I have developed the HTML page which will show the progress status of uploading file but if I am passing any other format file then that validation I am doing on Backend. In the controller I am checking if file is is different type then I am sending Model attribute message but I am not able to get that Model attribute on HTML Page. But if I remove the  tag where I am checking the progress of uploading file then Model Attribute message shows the message without any issue.

home.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input:file').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $('button:submit').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('button[type=submit]')
                .click(
                        function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $(this).prop('disabled', true);

                            var form = document.forms[0];
                            var formData = new FormData(form);

                            var ajaxReq = $
                                    .ajax({
                                        url : 'upload',
                                        type : 'POST',
                                        data : formData,
                                        cache : false,
                                        contentType : false,
                                        processData : false,
                                        xhr : function() {
                                            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();

                                            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(
                                                    event) {
                                                var perc = Math
                                                        .round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                                                $('#progressBar').text(
                                                        perc + '%');
                                                $('#progressBar').css('width',
                                                        perc + '%');
                                            };
                                                return xhr;                                                 
                                        },

                                    });
                        });
    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select File</label> <input class="form-control" type="file"
                    name="file">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled>Process
                    It</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br />

            <div class="progress">
            <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
                role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0"
                aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">0%</div>

        </div>
        <h3 th:text="${message}" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></h3>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is my HTML File and below is my Controller.

```java
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload")
    public String process(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file , Model model) throws Exception {

        String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename().toLowerCase();

        if(fileName.contains(".csv") == false) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Only .csv is acceptable");
            return "home";
        }

        return "success";
    }
}
```

I want to show Error message as well if any Incorrect format of File is passed on the same HTML page. Basically I want to achieve/print error or success message on the same page if any thing returned on the Post call. It will be really helpful if I will get any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign handlers to your post call:

```
var ajaxReq = $.post( "upload", function(){
  // add all your success logic here
})
.fail(function() {
  // add all your error logic here
});
```

Note that your backend checks if the string ".csv" is there but you should be aware that someone could upload a file like this: "file.csv.malware.exe". The endsWith() method seems more appropriate.